# why didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is not called

Tags: objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I am making an application in which I want to implement apple push notification  service.  I am following the step-by-step instructions given in [this tutorial](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services?dm_switcher=true).

But still, the methods are not called. I don't know what is causing the problem. Can anyone help me?

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken { 
        //NSString * token = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:deviceTokenencoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device Token=%@",deviceToken];
        NSLog(@"Device Token:%@",str);

        //NSLog(@"Device token is called");
        //const void *devTokenBytes = [deviceToken bytes];
        //NSLog(@"Device Token");
    }

    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err { 
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Error: %@", err];
        NSLog(@"Error:%@",str);    
    }
```

Comment: there is no need to add any other code just check it link http://stackoverflow.com/a/39849892/3269536

Answer (score 74):

I had the same issue: calling `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` invoked neither `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` nor `application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:`

I eventually resolved this issue with the help of Apple's technical note [TN2265](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html).

This is what I did:

First off, I double-checked that I am indeed [registering correctly for Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html), including verifying my provisioning profile for "aps-environment" key and the codesigning of the .app file itself. I had it all set up correctly.

I then had to debug Push Notification status messages in the console (you need to install  PersistentConnectionLogging.mobileconfig provisioning profile on your device and reboot it. See [TN2265](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html) under "Observing Push Status Messages"). I noticed that apns process starts a timer and calculates a minimum fire date, which made me suspect that the Push-Notification registration confirmation message, which is normally presented at this point, is supressed by APNS, as indicated in TN2265:

> **Resetting the Push Notifications Permissions Alert on iOS**
>
> The first time a push-enabled app registers for push notifications, iOS asks the user if they wish to receive notifications for that app. Once the user has responded to this alert it is not presented again unless the device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at least a day.
>
> If you want to simulate a first-time run of your app, you can leave the app uninstalled for a day. You can achieve the latter without actually waiting a day by setting the system clock forward a day or more, turning the device off completely, then turning the device back on.

So, I removed the app from the device, then manually changed the iPhone's date in Settings, rebooted the device, and re-installed the app.

The next time my code called `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes`, it received callbacks as expected.

This resolved the issue for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: The key point for me was that I was using an older development certificate on another machine. Transferring the newest certificate from the main development laptop fixed this issue.

Comment: After enable Push notifications is necessary to generate again the provisioning profiles.

Comment: Hi! although this is an old post, I found out that sometimes it will be fixed when you turn Off and On all the Notification settings of the app. Because last time I remember didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken was called then suddenly it was not. Hope it helps.

Comment: I only got this to work by adding another reset step: 1. Delete app 2. Reset Device 3. Forward clock 1+ days 4. Reset Device AGAIN 5. Now install and it should prompt the push notification alert

Comment: It’s also important to make sure that you don't have multiple "valid" copies of the same development provisioning profile, either in Xcode or on the device itself. Perhaps you created a new APN certificate and recreated your provisioning profile after the previous certificate expired. The old development profile is still valid as a development profile, but it will not be sufficient to enable APNs. You'll see a typical error about "no valid aps-entitlement blah blah".

Comment: Right click on the device in Xcode's Devices window to see the provisioning profiles, and delete all but the newest one for your target.

Comment: Confirmed. still exists in xcode 11.7, ios 13.7. Changing the date, hour and delete app and reboot phone = helped

Answer (score 66):

In iOS 8, some methods are deprecated. Follow the steps below for iOS 8 compatibility

### 1. Register notification

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion].floatValue >= 8.0)
{
    UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];    
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge)];
}
```

### 2. Add new 2 methods

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

//For interactive notification only
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    //handle the actions
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"declineAction"]){
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"answerAction"]){
    }
}
```

Note : above two new methods are required in iOS 8 in addition to `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` and `didReceiveRemoteNotification`..Otherwise delegate method will not be invoked.

See: [Remote Notification iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216632/remote-notification-ios-8)

Comment: Should those two new methods go in Appdelegate.m ?

Comment: - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}  Adding the following is dangerous, it crashed my phone and I am unable to even factory reset it at this point.

Comment: This is probably the answer you're looking for if you're ending up here. Oddly, the delegate were called earlier today without me adding one of these methods. Now it seems like I need them both.

Comment: my app crashes with this line `[application registerForRemoteNotifications];`

Answer (score 26):

In **iOS 8**, in addition to requesting push notification access differently, you also need to register differently.

Request Access:

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    // iOS 8
    UIUserNotificationSettings* settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
} else {
    // iOS 7 or iOS 6
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Handle registered device:

```
// New in iOS 8
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

// iOS 7 or iOS 6
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSString *token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    // Send token to server
}
```

Comment: Extremely helpful. I couldn't figure out why my notifications broke.

Comment: How can I get the token in iOS 8?

Comment: @Yossi it is stored in the "token" variable in ```application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:```

Comment: my app crashes with this line [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

Answer (score 16):

Bear in mind that remote notifications are not supported in the simulator. Therefore, if you run your app in the simulator, `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` won't be called.

Comment: @hochl: I updated my answer so that it more specifically answers the question.

Comment: Note that didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError won't get called either.  In fact, neither notification gets called if you disable push notifications for your app in Settings (whether on device or simulator).  Apple doesn't seem to regard this as an error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199935/didfailtoregisterforremotenotificationswitherror-user-refused-error

Answer (score 12):

Make sure you call in your code (update according to supported notification kinds)

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

and the provisioning profile is APNS enabled. You may need to re-download the provisioning profile after enabing APNS. If you have troubles and you get errors, then maybe you should create an Entitlements.plist and add the key "aps-environment" with value "development" or "production" depending on the kind of build (normally this key-value pair is contained in the provisioning profile, but sometimes Xcode mess with them).

Comment: Note: "and the provisioning profile is APNS enabled." Click on the top of you Project Tree > Capabilities > Push Notifications should be set to ON.

Answer (score 6):

If the provisioning profiles are used before to Enable and Configure Apple Push Notification service, you will need to redownload the provisioning profiles again.

Delete provisioning profiles from Xcode Organizer and from the iPhone/iPad.
Go to `Settings -> General -> Profiles -> [Your provisioning] -> Remove`.

Install the new downloaded provisioning profiles. Then clean and run the project from XCode. 
Now `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` should be called.

Comment: It work for me. just chose certification and provisioning which had register APNs for the app.

Comment: I deleted all provisioning profile from iphone (ios9) and then after Device Token is receiving .Spend four hour to fix this (although i learn a lot ) . Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try this it working for me ,

**First Step**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

In above method add below code

```
 UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
 if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                     |UIUserNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                     |UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
 } 
 else {
      UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
     }
```

**Second Step**

Add below code Function

```
 #ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
   {
  //register to receive notifications
  [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
  }

 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
  {
    //handle the actions
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"declineAction"]){
    }
   else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"answerAction"]){
   }
}
 #endif
```

You will get device Token in below function

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```

for detail answer please refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24488562/4527240)

Hope this is help for some one .

Answer (score 3):

I made a mistake and overlooked an implementation detail that lead me here. I tried to get fancy and ask the user for Push Notifications later in the application onboarding process, so I had my `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes`, `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` and `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` all in a custom UIView.

FIX: the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` and `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` need to be in the `UIApplicationDelegate` (`YourAppDelegate.m`) to be triggered.

seems obvious now, heh.

Comment: Yes the methods *need* to be in `AppDelegate`. Can't believe I wasted my past few hours on this simple answer

Answer (score 3):

Be sure that your internet connection is on.
This took me hours to get work notifications because of internet connection.

Answer (score 3):

If you have added push to an existing App ID, make sure you re-generate your provisioning profiles. If you don't, the profile will not know about your enabling of push on the App ID.

Answer (score 2):

```
-​(BOOL)application:(UIApplication​*)application​ didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary​*)launchOptions​{​​​​ ​​​​ ​​​​//​Override​point​for​customization​after​application​launch.
​​​​//​Add​the​view​controller’s​view​to​the​window​and​display. ​​​​[window​addSubview:viewController.view]; ​​​​[window​makeKeyAndVisible];
NSLog(@”Registering for push notifications...”);
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)]; 
​​​​return​YES;
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
}
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@”Device Token=%@”,deviceToken];
NSLog(@”%@”, str);


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @”Error: %@”, err]; NSLog(@”%@”, str);
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
}
for (id key in userInfo) { NSLog(@”key: %@, value: %@”, key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Minimal Requirement to Get Device Token:**
**No need to configure app id, provisioning or certificate etc** thus no code signing set to get the delegate method **didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken** called. 

I just created a new iOS project in Xcode 7 for single view with default settings and gave a random bundle id like com.mycompany.pushtest which is not configured in apple dev portal. 
With the following code, I'm getting my device token in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method on my iPad with **internet** access to WIFI. My device is attached and I'm just running the app directly from xcode and viewing the values in xcode's console.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions   

{  
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])  
    {  
        UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound);  
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];  
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];  
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        // Register for Push Notifications, if running iOS version < 8  
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];  
    }  
    return YES;  
}  


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: %@", deviceToken);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    NSLog(@"NotificationSettings: %@", notificationSettings);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a different issue wherein my push notification callbacks were getting hijacked by the 3rd party libraries, that I had included, namely Firebase. These libraries swizzle push notification callback methods to get the callbacks.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

After wasting the most annoying 3h, here are the steps to fix the issue:

1. Delete the app
2. Reset the device
3. Run again

It just worked

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me, because I reset & deleted all the data on the phone (wanted a dev phone to use).  This prevented APN from connecting at all after setting up the phone again.

I tried all sorts of things, but the only thing that fixed it was setting the phone up to work with a carrier under a new SIM card.

This link offers more hints as to what might have been going on: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

It says that APN tries to connect preferentially via carrier / towers as opposed to wifi.  Maybe the issue also was something was going on with the router blocking port 5223 on the wifi network, but I doubt it because it worked fine on the prior day before the global reset occurred.

Answer (score 1):

I have a point on this.Recently I too face this problem.I have done everything 
according to documentation but delegate method was not calling.Finally I saw 
one post saying that problem with the network.Then I have changed network and 
it works fine.So take care about network also because few networks can block 
the APNS.

Answer (score 0):

For me what solved it was going to the build settings and under the code signing section, manually selecting the code signing identity and provisioning profile. Apparently the automatic setting wasn't picking-up the correct one and therefore the app wasn't properly authorized.

Answer (score 0):

Also, don't forget to check the system status at Apple https://developer.apple.com/system-status/.

I'd tried all the solutions posted above but in the end the fault was because the APNS service was down! The next day all was working again as expected.

Also, you have a typo in your callback method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)appdidRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```

As Rupesh pointed out the correct method name is:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```

That's probably why you never received the token in your case!

Comment: Actually method name is incorrect, it should be

     - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken

There is a space between to parameters

Comment: Thanks, have updated the answer to include your comment. Pretty sure this is the solution to the OPs problem but we may never find out!

Answer (score 0):

if shut down push message of app,

appdidRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken   will never be called

Answer (score 0):

You need to call registerForNotifications method from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
 func registerForNotifications(){

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.delegate = self
            center.requestAuthorization(options:[.alert,.sound,.badge]) { (granted, error) in
                if granted{
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }else{

                    print("Notification permission denied.")

                }
            }

        } else {

            // For iOS 9 and Below
            let type: UIUserNotificationType = [.alert,.sound,.badge];
            let setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: type, categories: nil);
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(setting);
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

        let token = String(format: "%@", deviceToken as CVarArg).trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "<>")).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        print(token)

    }


extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("Handle push from foreground”)

        let info = ((notification.request.content.userInfo as NSDictionary).value(forKey: "aps") as! NSDictionary)
        if let type = info.value(forKey: "type") as? Int{
            if type == 0 {  

         // notification received ,Handle your notification here

            }
        }
    }

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        print("Handle push from background or closed")

        let info = ((response.notification.request.content.userInfo as NSDictionary).value(forKey: "aps") as! NSDictionary)
        if let type = info.value(forKey: "type") as? Int{
            if type == 0 {   

            // notification received ,Handle your notification here
            }
        }
    }
}
```