# didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: user refused error?

Tags: ios, push

If the user refuses the enable push notifications, we'll get an error, through didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError. Does anybody know what the code in the NSError object will be in this case (to differentiate it from, say, no connection being available)?

Comment: You should really award the answer to Jerred - his is the correct answer. I just had to re-verify this for one of my company's clients. Downloaded our Enterprise app (which uses production push services), disallowed all notifications when asked, and the app still got a token. Enabling them in Settings, restarting the app, then disabling them in Settings, restart the app - in all cases the token is properly returned.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't think your initial statement (always) holds true. If an app is properly signed with a valid provisioning profile, calling `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` will result in `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` regardless of the user's Notifications choices in the Settings app. From my experience, the only times I have seen `application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:` get called was because of an improperly signed app. The error in question mentioned "no valid aps-environment entitlement found for application".

Answer (score 21):

Although this question is old, and agree with most of the @Jerred's answer, i thought of posting an updated answer anyway.

The answer to main question in the thread is **NO**.

**application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:** gets called when the app is signed with incorrect provisioning profile.

Also,

**application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:** gets called only when user enables at-least one of the badge, banner/alert or sound setting in the notification center (in Settings app) for your app.

There are scenarios where iOS will not call either of these methods

- When user refuses to grant permissions for app to send push notifications
- When there is no network connectivity and user granted permissions to send push notifications.
- When user disables the push notifications for app from notification center in Settings app.

Comment: That's a good article except for one part: "There are separate environments for APNS: **sandbox (for development and ad hoc builds)**, and production. Each has its own certificate, and the provisioning procedure needs to be repeated between the two.". Ad-hoc builds actually hit the production APNS: "The operating system establishes a persistent connection to the sandbox environment for development builds; ad hoc and distribution builds connect to the production environment." from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG42

Comment: It would be great to update the answer with what the article described as best practices, since now it is not available anymore.

Comment: Agree with @leolobato, the link to the article is not valid anymore.

Comment: One thing has changed: "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" is still called even if all your notifications are turned off.

Answer (score 3):

To my experience, `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:` method is reserved for more serious cases which prevents the app from even showing the notification permission request dialog to the user. The cases that I know of include the app being run on devices that do not support push notifications, (e.g. Simulator) or some misconfiguration in the aps-environment entitlement in the app binary.

Answer (score 2):

For me there was 2 files that held the entitlements, here I added Aps-enviroment : production and it worked after[image]