# application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: Not Firing When Using Developer Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

In Ad Hoc builds I see the `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` event called but not when I use a DEBUG build using a developer provisioning profile.  The Ad Hoc and Developer Provisioning Profile are using the same App ID.

App ID Screenshot:
[image]

When running using the developer provisioning profile I did see the alert asking about whether or not to enable push notifications.  I chose to use push notifications, but then the event `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` never occurred.  Note that the event for `application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:` also does not occur.

Note that in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` I have:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert];
   // Other code...
}
```

I'm pretty puzzled by this one.

**Other Notes:**

- My iPad 2 and iPod 4 I am using are NOT jail broken
- I was seeing the dreaded no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application error, but this resolved after regenerating my development provisioning profile.
- A co-worker of mine has seen this same issue (works on Ad Hoc but not developer) on projects with previous companies.

Comment: so the alert view for confirm to allow push notification is appear and you click allow and nothing happend ?

Comment: @Malek_Jundi Right.  :(  Unfortunately, that alert only shows up once per day - see [why didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is not called](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8036052/590956) and  [Resetting the Push Notifications Permissions Alert on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG42).

Comment: yeah i know but you don't have to wait 1 day just modify the device date to be tomorrow :)

Comment: @Malek_Jundi Event decided to fire today.  Didn't seem to have anything to do with that alert (since I didn't see it today when things started working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Same Code Worked Next Day

The event `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken` is working now (the next day).  Note that this **seems to have had nothing to do with the alert** asking whether you want to enable push notifications as I didn't see this alert when it began working.

One thing I still find odd is that yesterday using Ad Hoc build the event `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken` fired EVERY TIME I launched the app.  However, a DEBUG build with a developer provisioning profile never fired at all.  Same code this morning works (and fires every time using a DEBUG build with a developer provisioning profile)....  Something in the device (internal timer / timeout) must have reset.

### Sample Code

Below is the code I used in the event receiving the deviceToken.  It uses Urban Airship as the provider to the Apple Push Notification Server (APNS).  I've removed the username and passwords from the code.  I hope this is useful to others who are trying to figure things out.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
        didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSString *tokenStr = [[[[deviceToken description]
                            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""]
                           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                          stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"Device Token (raw): %@", deviceToken);
    NSLog(@"Device Token (string): %@", tokenStr);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Device Token"
                                                 message:tokenStr
                                                delegate:nil
                                       cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                       otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil] autorelease];
    [alert show];

    // Code to send token to server
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"https://go.urbanairship.com/api/device_tokens/%@", tokenStr];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:
                               [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
#if APP_STORE_RELEASE
    [request addBasicAuthenticationHeaderWithUsername:@"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                                          andPassword:@"bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"];
#else
    [request addBasicAuthenticationHeaderWithUsername:@"cccccccccccccccccccccc"
                                          andPassword:@"dddddddddddddddddddddd"];
#endif
    request.requestMethod = @"PUT";
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

Note that the description of the NSData will return a Hex string that begins with a "<" and ends with a ">".  In between are spaces.  My original approach was to convert the NSData into a string using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` but this is wrong (since **you want the token as a hexadecimal string**).