# Remote Notification iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, apple-push-notifications

How can I get the Device Token for remote notification in iOS 8?
I used the method `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` in `AppDelegate` in iOS < 8, and it returned the device token. But in iOS 8, it does not.

Comment: This really worked..! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086599/why-didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken-is-not-called/26115072#26115072

Answer (score 180, accepted):

#### Read the code in UIApplication.h.

You will know how to do that.

First:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

add Code like this

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
  UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert 
      | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge 
      | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
  [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
#endif
} else {
  UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
  [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
}
```

**if you not using both Xcode 5 and Xcode 6** ,try this code

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
  UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
      |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound
      |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
  [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
} else {
  UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
  [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
}
```

**(Thanks for @zeiteisen @dmur 's remind)**

---

Second:

Add this Function

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    //handle the actions
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"declineAction"]){
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"answerAction"]){
    }
}
#endif
```

And your can get the deviceToken in

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```

if it still not work , use this function and NSLog the ***error***

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Comment: This.  Sophomorically enough, Apple failed to update their documentation for `UIUserNotificationSettings` or `UIApplication` talking about how this is required for iOS 8.  It's buried in their API diffs instead.

Comment: This will crash on iOS versions below iOS 8. #ifdef is a COMPILER function, and is evaluated at compile time. You still need a run-time check!

Comment: @DanVanWinkle because your XCode not the latest one.

Comment: That's not true. Try running this code on an iOS 7 or below device. It will crash. If you compile the code on the latest Xcode, ONLY the first half of the code will be ran, and the #else part will not even be compiled into code.

Comment: __IPHONE_8_0 is work in XCode5. I'm using this code in my project.I try it in iOS6 devise.

Comment: I use xcode 6 beta 6 and #ifdef __IPHONE_8_0 work with below ios 8. So I must change to `if(NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)`

Comment: Use this macro to check for iOS 8: #define isAtLeastiOS8 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) . __IPHONE_8_0 is not a good check because you want this code to continue to run on future versions also.

Comment: @er0 Yes, but __IPHONE_8_0 will also be defined in future versions.  Just as __IPHONE_7_0 works under iOS 8... so really, you can use either.

Comment: @er0 Take a look at the header file Availability.h and you'll see what I mean... you can command-click on __IPHONE_8_0 to bring up the file.  There you'll see that every version up to and including the current is #defined, not just the current one.

Comment: That said, in this case the #ifdef is unnecessary, unless your team is using both Xcode 5 and Xcode 6. Instead you should do an `if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {` check, as zeiteisen does in his answer.

Comment: This is actually incorrect and should be voted down. The application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings: method will not be called until you call the UIApplication registerForRemoteNotification method. You don't call that in that method.

Comment: @GregG `application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:` will be called after `[application registerUserNotificationSettings:]` (user will be prompted to allow notifications).

Comment: Little bit correction for deprecated enum UIRemoteNotificationType:
NS_ENUM_DEPRECATED_IOS(3_0, 8_0, "Use UIUserNotificationType for user notifications and registerForRemoteNotifications for receiving remote notifications instead.");

So, for iOS 8 and later you must use UIUserNotificationTypeBadge, UIUserNotificationTypeSound, UIUserNotificationTypeAlert.
(UIUserNotificationType for new versions, UIRemoteNotificationType - for older).                     
Enums defined in <UIKit/UIApplication.h> and <UIKit/UIUserNotificationSettings.h>

Comment: If you want the code to compile under xcode 5.x there is also this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25871600/756809

Comment: `#ifdef` is not a good way to support new APIs, it means your app will crash on devices running iOS7.
`respondsToSelector` is the correct way to do the check in all cases.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding what is supposed to happen here? I have added this code, but the application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken never gets called on my iOS8 iPhone.  didRegisterUserNotificationSettings **is** called, is there something more that I have to do there?

Comment: You have to call `completionHandler();` when you are done in `handleActionWithIdentifier` as mentioned in Apple Docs

Comment: You saved my skin! I've been having troubles with push notifications for about 3 days now ... and this post had the key! I wasn't receiving new tokens even if I change from develop to adhoc apps .... I believe the problem was that I did't implement didRegisterUserNotificationSettings ... Once again thanks a lot!

Answer (score 75):

The way to register for iOS 8 and keep supporting older versions

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                         |UIUserNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                         |UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
} else {
    UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
}
```

and in the app delegate add

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

iOS8 can receive silent notificaions without asking for permission. Call 
`- (void)registerForRemoteNotifications`. After this  `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` will be called

Note: the callback with the token is only called if the application has successfully registered for user notifications with the function below or if Background App Refresh is enabled.

Check the Settings for you app if any notification type is enabled. If not, you will not get a device token.

You are now able to obtain silent notifications with

```
aps {
content-available: 1
}
```

in the notification payload

But notifications that appear still needs permission. Call

```
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
```

This code should ask for permission.

You should now be ready to get push notifications

Comment: thank you for the `OS8 can receive silent notifications without asking for permission` bit. That was driving me crazy and this is the only place I found that helpful bit!

Comment: @zeiteisen, in your first `if` statement, you should be using `UIUserNotificationTypeSound` instead of `UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound`, since `UIRemoteNotificationType` is deprecated in iOS 8.

Comment: Can someone explain why the callback with the token is only called when Background App Refresh is enabled? I though it should be called when the Push Notification permission is enabled...

Answer (score 15):

In my case I had made the necessary updates to request push notification access for iOS 7 and iOS 8, however I had not implemented the new callback for when an iOS 8 user grants access. I needed to add this method to my app delegate.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Xamarin.iOS to build your mobile application, you can use this snippet of code to request push notification registration

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8,0))
{
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
    UIUserNotificationSettings settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(userNotificationTypes, null);
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
}
else
{
    UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationTypes);
}
```

Also you will need to override `DidRegisterUserNotificationSettings` method to get the device token returned from the APNS server:

```
public override void DidRegisterUserNotificationSettings(UIApplication application, UIUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings)
{
    application.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Madao (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24488562/859742) is right but....

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
```

should be more "correct"

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
```

Those flags have the same bit mask values and thats why both would work but `UIUserNotificationSettings` requires `UIUserNotificationType` not `UIRemoteNotificationType`.

Apart from that I would call

```
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

In the `AppDelegate` method (depending on the granted rights),

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: UIUserNotificationTypeBadge and UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge are same bit masks but mean different things =)

Answer (score 0):

I thing the better way to keep backward compatibility we can go with this approach, it is working for my case hope work for you. Also pretty easy to understand.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
    UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
```