# Push Notification in iOS 8 - UISwitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, ios8, xcode6

I created UISwitch to enable/disable push notifications that should be supported by both iOS 7 and iOS 8. I am trying to figure out how to get this working in iOS 8. Can't figure out what to fill in the following blank:

```
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{

    .......... fill in here...for iOS 8.........................
}

else
{
    UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
    BOOL turnedOffFromWithinNotificaitonCenter = (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone);

    if (turnedOffFromWithinNotificaitonCenter){
        _remindersSwitch.on = FALSE;
    }
    else{
        _remindersSwitch.on = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check it oot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216632/remote-notification-ios-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notifications now use a `UIUserNotificationSettings` object to encapsulate this sort of information. The types are still contained within there. As such, the 'blank' would be:

```
UIUserNotificationSettings* currentSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
UIUserNotificationType enabledTypes = currentSettings.types;

BOOL turnedOffFromWithinNotificaitonCenter = ((enabledTypes & UIUserNotificationTypeNone) == UIUserNotificationTypeNone);

if (turnedOffFromWithinNotificaitonCenter){
    _remindersSwitch.on = FALSE;
}
else{
    _remindersSwitch.on = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: thanks! what about this [application unregisterForRemoteNotifications]; ?

Comment: `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` is still valid, that hasn't been deprecated

Comment: In fairness, Apple does say "You should call this method in rare circumstances only". You shouldn't need to call it all the time.