# I need to figure out how to turn off badge, sound and alert in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, ios8

I have this piece of code that works in iOS7. It gives me the ability to shut off sound, alert and badge. If `showMessage,showBadge or show sound` is set to zero the corresponding UIremote type is turned off as well. As many of you know, iOS8 remote notifications has changed. Can someone please direct me how to make this work for iOS 8?

```
    UIRemoteNotificationType notificationType = UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone;
    if (showMessage == 1 )
        notificationType |= UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert;
    if (showBadge == 1 )
        notificationType |= UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge;
    if (showSound == 1 )
        notificationType |= UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:notificationType];
```

This is what I tried, but I get the error No visible @interface 'UIApplication' declares the selector 'registerForUserNotificationSettings:'

```
     UIUserNotificationType  userNotificationType = UIUserNotificationTypeNone;
    if (showMessage == 1 )
        userNotificationType |= UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
    if (showBadge == 1 )
        userNotificationType |= UIUserNotificationTypeBadge;
    if (showSound == 1 )
        userNotificationType |= UIUserNotificationTypeSound;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForUserNotificationSettings:userNotificationType];
```

Comment: Potentially related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24488562/1301654

Answer (score -1):

In your code you are passing UIUserNotificationType object but instead you need to pass UIUserNotificationSettings object.

```
UIUserNotificationType notificarionType = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:notificarionType categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
```