# IOS locked screen notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, swift2, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to get three options when you swipe to the left on the lock screen as yes no and cancel in iPhone when the screen is locked..
For example as shown in [API for swiping to the left on lock screen - iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068244/api-for-swiping-to-the-left-on-lock-screen-ios-8)

Comment: You mean you want 3 option when you swipe on a notification on the lockscreen? The example you liked in your question describes just that, they add yes and no but you could also add cancel.

Comment: So u mean to say it's possible to add three events or buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the lock screen can have max 2 button:

> In iOS 8 and later, the lock screen, notification banners, and
>   notification entries in Notification Center can display one or two
>   custom actions.

If the alert is displayed modally you can use more:

> Modal alerts can display up to four. When the user
>   selects a custom action, iOS notifies your app so that you can perform
>   the task associated with that action.

But there is no way to fore this.

Read the full spec in [Registering Your Actionable Notification Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW26)