# Testing if push notification is turned on

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

**NOTE:** This was apparently due to some sort of corruption in the Settings, the code was apparently fine all along...

---

Following the conversation in this thread: [Remote Notification iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216632/remote-notification-ios-8), I added this boilerplate code to my app:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge categories:nil]];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert];
}
if ([[inLaunchOptions allKeys] containsObject:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) {
    [appTracking registerPush:[inLaunchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]];
}
```

I also added the `application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings` handler, which calls a single line of code, `[application registerForRemoteNotifications]`. This code **is** called when the app starts.

Reading that thread, it is suggested that this is all that is required, and that this will cause `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` to be called. But that is definitely **not** happening in my app.

Did I miss a step, or simply mis-understand how to set this up?

Comment: Are you sending the token to your server and using that to send push notifications through Apple's server?

Comment: Trying to, yes. But I can't get the token.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the following line `[application registerForRemoteNotifications]` after `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert];` iOS 8 condition

Good Luck

Comment: Sorry, it appears we were both editing. I do have that line of code, it just never gets called.

Comment: do you test on a real device or simulator?

Comment: you need to add the following line [application registerForRemoteNotifications] after iOS 8 condition. Good Luck

Comment: I have that line of code, and I can see it is being called.

Comment: Don't add it in the callback method. Add it in didFinishLuanchWithOptions. This line is the one which call application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings

Comment: OMG. Ok well apparently the entire problem was due to the system settings being screwed up. I went to Settings->Notifications and simply flicked on switch on and off and presto, the message started arriving again. No, it was not the "allow" switch, that was on from the start. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                             categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

Comment: No luck. I see that you have basically called registerForRemoteNotifications earlier than I do, but that doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: the idea is about [application registerForRemoteNotifications]