# Push notification sound doesn't work on iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications

Hi trying to fix a issue discovered other, the device is not playing the notification sound if it is locked. If device is unlocked the sound is played this issue happens only on iOS 8.x.

- I test other apps like gmail and the same no notification sound when the device is locked
- The sound is enabled from the notification center
- The register for remote notification is done correctly like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24488562/2103088)

The only issue is that when the device is locked there is no notification sound even the lock screen is not lighting up like on previous versions.

Any solution to fix this ?

**UPDATE:** 
After updating the device to iOS 8.3 seams that all iOS bugs that i notice before now are fixed , and the notification sound too, but I still what to know if there is some solution for this issue, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make the same noob mistake as me ? :D

I had the **Do Not Disturb mode turned on** and it prevented the device lock screen from waking and no sound played.

If you did, turn off Do No Disturb.

Note: the Do Not Disturb toggle can be accessed by pulling up from the bottom of the iPhone screen. It's the crescent moon icon that's next to the rotation lock button.

Comment: yes, thank you that was the problem , and now i'm feeling like a big noob :(

Comment: Ha, you're not alone mate. I did the biggest face palm after I realised it :D

Answer (score 0):

Along a similar vein to @Zhang, I wasn't getting any sounds because I had sound volume turned down all the way in Settings > Sounds.  There is a "Ringers and Alerts" volume slider (top of the screen, in iOS 8.1 at least) that I had all the way down, and after increasing this volume slider I was able to hear the alert sounds.