# Remote notifications for iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In the notifications app is not registred for son and badge.

This is my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:     (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //-- Set Notification
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.000000) {
        UIUserNotificationSettings * settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {
        //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
```

Someone has an explanation? Thank you

Comment: what is wrong? what do you expect?

Comment: Take a look at `-[NSProcessInfo isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:]`.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 8 need some change in push notification delegate methods and explained clearly in [*this link*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086599/why-didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken-is-not-called/26115072#26115072)

Also don't call registerForRemoteNotifications for iOS 8 because its deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please use this code,

```
       #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
            UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
        } else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
             registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
             (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
              UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
              UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
        }
    #else
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
         registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
          UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |


 UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
#endif
```

and for delegate methods,

```
  #pragma mark - Push Notification

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    // Prepare the Device Token for Registration (remove spaces and < >)
    NSString *TokenID = [[[[deviceToken description]
                           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
                          stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                         stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];


    [ApplicationPreferences setTokenId:TokenID];
    if (DEBUG_MODE) {
        NSLog(@"device token - %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device Token = %@",TokenID]);
        NSUUID *oNSUUID = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
        NSLog(@"Vendor token - %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device Token = %@",[oNSUUID UUIDString]]);
    }

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
    if (DEBUG_MODE) {
        NSLog(@"Push Error- %@",[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Error: %@", err]);
    }
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the iOS 8 version you forgot the brackets

```
(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound)
```

Comment: I already tried like that. That changes nothing. In notification i dont have sounds and badges enable.